# How can I generate key scheduling for AES 256 bit key

Tags: encryption, aes, cryptanalysis, cryptographic-hardware

I want to implement AES algorithm,instead of 128 bit key encryption I wanted to do it for 256.But I’m stuck at point creating scheduling for 256 key generation.
Can anyone help in this.

Comment: Er, you realise that AES keys can only be 128, 192 or 256 bits? There's no AES-512.

Comment: If you need to know how to handle 256 bit keys, well, section 5.2 of FIPS 197 is a start (with Appendix A giving a real test vector, useful for finding misunderstandings).  Is there anything specific about that you don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @poncho, you have to read FIPS 197 (https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/fips/nist.fips.197.pdf). You should look on paragraph 5.2 Key Expansion. This one have a pseudo code. Also you can look on implementation in Go's runtime (https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/aes/block.go).